# Importing .jar in Jython

Tags: python, jar, import, jython

I was looking at docs about this but I can't figure it out. I'm currently coding Bukkit plugins in Jython and everything works fine except importing jars (other plugins) aka hooking into them.

I found this while checking for questions/answers on stackoverflow, but it's not working:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append("%s/plugins/TagAPI.jar"%os.getcwd())
import org.kitteh.tag
```

I get this as error:

```
20:19:35 [SEVERE] org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Traceback (most rece
nt call last):
File "<iostream>", line 6, in <module>
ImportError: No module named kitteh
```

Actually, there is kitteh, look at this part of source:

https://github.com/KittehOrg/TagAPI/blob/master/src/main/java/org/kitteh/tag/PlayerReceiveNameTagEvent.java

Thanks for answering! :)

Comment: what is `os.path.exists("plugins/TagAPI.jar")`? (`os.getcwd()` code breaks if you run the code from a different directory.) Is `TagAPI.jar` in `CLASSPATH`? Have your tried to import a concrete class e.g., `from org.kitteh.tag import AsyncPlayerReceiveNameTagEvent`?